# Nginx URL proxy to server

Tags: nginx, proxy, url

I'm trying to

- redirect all traffic from www.example.com and example.com to old-www.website.com
- proxy all traffic from example.com/forum (and www) to forum server @ 192.168.100.100

I've tried the following config but it keeps returning me to my old website
When I remove the `location /` the forum is not loading and I'm getting `404's` since the server is trying to load files @ `example.com/` instead of `example.com/forum`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    location /forum/ {
        proxy_pass         http://192.168.100.100/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }

    location / {
        return 302 $scheme://www.old-site.com;
    }
}
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the extra `/` in your `proxy_pass` statement. This causes nginx to use `/` as the URI with your forum always.

Try this:

```
location ~ /forum(/.+)? {
     proxy_pass http://192.168.100.100$1;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Here I assume that you want the URL `http://www.example.com/forum/something` get proxied to `http://192.168.100.100/something`. Without the regular expression match and `$1` in the `proxy_pass`, it would proxy to `http://192.168.100.100/forum/something`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Here’s a very simple example that redirects clients to a new domain name:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.old-name.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.new-name.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I'm using nginx, my main focus is on solving the forum url/proxy issue how can I solve that?

Comment: try new answer, it may help you

Comment: I need to proxy the forum server on any url starting /forum